# Python code runs in PyCharm but not when called from Excel VBA Macro

Tags: python, excel, vba

When I run the code below from PyCharm, it works.

```
import webbrowser
from dotenv import load_dotenv
ComputerName = {
    'Computer1':'ComputerOne.env',
    'Computer2':'ComputerTwo.env'

}  # Dictionary of computer names and their respective environment files

load_dotenv(ComputerName[os.getenv('COMPUTERNAME')]) # Load the environment variables for the computer
chrome_path = os.getenv('chrome_path') + ' %s --incognito' # Path to chrome browser
url = 'https://www.google.com' # URL
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new(url) # Open the URL in chrome browser
```

When I run this code using a VBA Macro in Excel, the chrome_path is `None` and the code won't work. `os.getenv('chrome_path')` does not work when this code is being called from Excel VBA Macro.

Why?

The Excel VBA Macro is like this:

```
Sub Open_Chrome_From_Excel()

ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lrow As Range
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExePath, PythonScriptPath As String
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim FileSavePath As String
    
  
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileSavePath = FileSavePath
    FileToCreate.Write ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")


PythonExePath = PythonExePath
PythonScriptPath = "py " & PythonScriptPath

objShell.Run PythonScriptPath
        
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Below is Chat GPT's answer. Is there really no better solution for this?

When you run Python code from Excel, the environment variables may not be automatically available within the Python process. This can lead to `os.getenv('chrome_path')` returning `None` because the `chrome_path` environment variable is not set or accessible from the Excel environment.

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

1. **Set the environment variable in your Excel environment**: If you have control over the Excel environment where you are running the Python code, you can set the `chrome_path` environment variable there. The process of setting environment variables in Excel can vary depending on the specific version and configuration you are using.
2. **Pass the Chrome path as an argument**: Instead of relying on the environment variable, you can pass the Chrome path as an argument to your Python script when calling it from Excel. Modify your Python script to accept a command-line argument for the Chrome path and retrieve it using `sys.argv`:

```py
import sys

chrome_path = sys.argv[1] + ' %s --incognito'
```

Then, when calling the Python script from Excel, provide the Chrome path as an argument:

```
python your_script.py /path/to/chrome
```

3. **Hardcode the Chrome path in the Python script**: If the Chrome path is fixed and doesn't need to be changed dynamically, you can hardcode it directly in your Python script:

```py
chrome_path = '/path/to/chrome' + ' %s --incognito'
```

This eliminates the need for relying on environment variables altogether.

Choose the option that best suits your requirements and the specific constraints of your Excel environment.